# Unable to change permission of a file in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, immutability

I tried to remove the immutable permission of hosts file with "sudo chattr -i /etc/hosts" command but it is not changing. Can anyone please help me with this.
[image]

I tried to forcefully write the file with :wq! In vim still the file is not changed

Comment: `777` perms for `/etc/hosts` an easy feast for DNS spoofing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, you can solve this problem using:

```
sudo chattr -ai /etc/hosts
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions.